# Autocomplete URL AJAX

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, ajax, autocomplete

I want to know where is gsmarena.com put ajax url when they do a search. I tried to explore the source of it and I found this function:

```
function autocompleteLoadList() {
    if (AUTOCOMPLETE_LIST !== null) return;
    AUTOCOMPLETE_LIST = false;
    var xhr;
    if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
        xhr = new XMLHttpRequest
    } else if (window.ActiveXObject) {
        try {
            xhr = new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.XMLHTTP")
        } catch (x) {
            try {
                xhr = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP")
            } catch (x) {
                AUTOCOMPLETE_LIST = null
            }
        }
    }
    xhr.open("GET", AUTOCOMPLETE_LIST_URL, true);
    xhr.onreadystatechange = function(e) {
        if (xhr.readyState == 4)
            if (xhr.status == 200) {
                var data;
                if (window.JSON) {
                    data = JSON.parse(xhr.responseText)
                } else {
                    data = eval("(" + xhr.responseText + ")")
                }
                AUTOCOMPLETE_MAKERS = data[0];
                AUTOCOMPLETE_LIST = data[1];
                if (typeof AUTOCOMPLETE_CALLBACK != "undefined") AUTOCOMPLETE_CALLBACK()
            } else {
                AUTOCOMPLETE_LIST = null
            }
    };
    xhr.send(null)
}
```

http://cdn2.gsmarena.com/w/js/autocomplete.js?ver=2

I do not know where they put the url to doing a search.

when I open the network tab in Google Chrome console there is also no url to POST or GET. how could they do it?

Comment: 143, 198, 360, 374, are the lines you should check for that info, copy paste this to go to the source code: view-source:http://www.gsmarena.com/

Comment: there is just JS files ads in lines you mentioned @ADASein

Comment: hahaha.. gsmarena trying to hide the generated json by changing extension to jpg. lol. check line number 19 . AUTOCOMPLETE_LIST_URL = "/quicksearch-6376.jpg"; . http://www.gsmarena.com/quicksearch-6376.jpg